# System gets restarted with this error

Tags: windows-xp

I get this error with a blue screen

> STOP: c0000210 {Fatal System Error}
> The windows Subsystem system process terminated unexpectedly with status of 0xc0000005 (0x7c9106c3 0x00c8ed04).
> The system has been shut down.
>
> Beginning dump of physical memory
> ...

Any workaround for this? Which is this error?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en;156669&spid=3071&sid=74) Microsoft Support documentation  for this error.

(have fixed the link)

Comment: Note: change that 'es' in the URL to 'en' and you get the English version: http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en;156669&spid=3071&sid=74